# LinkedHashSet JSONArray Android

Tags: java, android, json

Es la primera vez que me planteo usar LinkedHashSet en mi código de Android y no estoy muy seguro de si se puede usar y como usarlo.

Tengo una clase (Class_1) donde se extrae de un JSONObject, usando la librería loopj para la connexión y trasnferencia de json, un array el cual tiene un número indeterminado de objetos dentro cada uno de ellos compuestos por 4 elementos:

Id (unico)

Temperatura

Humedad

Insertado (this is timestamp)

Estos datos provienen de mi servidor, donde en PHP y a través de un JOIN de tablas prepara un json. Es por este motivo que en dicho elemento recibido existen objetos duplicados.

```
{"result":[{"Id":"621","temperatura":"35","humedad":"45","Insertado":"2016-08-30 12:53:36"},{......},{.....}...]}
```

Éstos es almacenado en un Objeto "parametrosdht11" y luego es usado a través de una interface en una segunda clase(Class_2) donde serán procesados para crear una gráfica.

```
for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject parametrosdht11 = cast.getJSONObject(i);
                loopjListener.onLoopjTaskCompletedBarometro(parametrosdht11, i);

            }
            loopjListener.onLoopCompleteBarometro();
```

Hasta aquí todo funciona bien, por este motivo no pongo todo el código, ahora bien, me veo en la necesidad de eliminar objetos duplicados (dejando tan solo uno de ellos) dentro del Array Json que envío a la class_2. Por este motivo me planteo usar LinkedHashSet.

Agradecería si me pudieran ayudar, pues no tengo muy claro que pueda usar esta interface y en segundo lugar no se como implemetarlo, por tanto agradecería un ejemplo en código, como el subject pone, estoy en Java pero en Android.
Gracias.

**Actualización:**

Ejemplo del Json, como se observa las repeticiones....

```
{"result":[{"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29","Id_press":"1","presion":"34","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 16:18:36","Id_alt":"1","altitud":"11","Insertado_alt":"2016-08-16 16:37:57"},
```

{"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29","Id_press":"3","presion":"55","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 16:22:14","Id_alt":"1","altitud":"11","Insertado_alt":"2016-08-16 16:37:57"},{"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29","Id_press":"4","presion":"55.45","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 16:22:42","Id_alt":"1","altitud":"11","Insertado_alt":"2016-08-16 16:37:57"},{"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29","Id_press":"6","presion":"50","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 18:26:27","Id_alt":"1","altitud":"11","Insertado_alt":"2016-08-16 16:37:57"},{"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29","Id_press":"7","presion":"50","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 18:28:13","Id_alt":"1","altitud":"11","Insertado_alt":"2016-08-16 16:37:57"},{"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29","Id_press":"8","presion":"50","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 18:28:45","Id_alt":"1","altitud":"11","Insertado_alt":"2016-08-16 16:37:57"},{"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29","Id_press":"1","presion":"34","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 .blabla.....

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes con `LinkedHashSet`? ¿Por qué optar por esa clase cuando bien podrías usar `List` implementado con `ArrayList`? ¿Existe alguna necesidad de que los elementos sean únicos, y en caso de ser cierto, qué define esta unicidad?

Comment: Hola. Sí, como digo en la explicación, hay elementos repetidos, esta repetición viene dada por la fecha, por tanto  necesito que se eliminen los repetidos ya que tengo que trasladar a un eje X la fecha y a un eje Y la presión y por otro lado la temperatura (Gráfica doble). Como vienen de un JOIN de varias tablas, existen duplicidades. Pongo en unos minutos el ejemplo que recibo enn Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas primero tener una clase donde vayas a almacenar la información que recibes de la interacción con el servicio web. Esta clase debe implementar los métodos `equals` y `hashCode`, puesto que `LinkedHashSet` utiliza estos métodos para comprobar la unicidad del objeto a agregar en el conjunto.

Aquí te dejo un breve ejemplo de cómo esto podría funcionar para ti. (Es breve y para ilustrar, **debes adaptar este código a tus necesidades**)

```
public class Temperatura {
    //nombre obtenido en base a la temperatura
    private int idTemperatura;
    private int temperatura;
    private Date insertadoTemp;
    private int idPresion;
    private int presion;
    private Date insertadoPresion;
    private int idAltitud;
    private int altitud;
    private Date insertadoAltitud;

    //getters y setters...

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //hashcode basado en la fecha de inserción de temperatura
        return insertadoTemp != null ? insertadoTemp.hashCode() : idTemperatura;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (o != null && o.getClass().equals(this.getClass())) {
            Temperatura otro = (Temperatura)o;
            //asumiendo que utilizas Java 7 usa el código de abajo
            //result = Objects.equals(this.insertadoTemp, otro.insertadoTemp);
            //si usas Java 6 y otros
            result = (this.insertadoTemp != null && otro.insertadoTemp != null
                && this.insertadoTemp.equals(otro.insertadoTemp))
                || (this.insertadoTemp == null && otro.insertadoTemp == null);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d-%s", id, insertadoTemp.toString());
    }
}

//...

//Agregando elementos de tipo Temperatura a LinkedHashSet
Set<Temperatura> setTemperaturas = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Temperatura t1 = new Temperatura();
t1.setId(1);
t1.setDate(stringToDate("2016-09-02 04:00:00"));
Temperatura t2 = new Temperatura();
t2.setId(2);
t2.setDate(stringToDate("2016-09-03 04:00:00"));
Temperatura t3 = new Temperatura();
t3.setId(3);
//tiene la misma fecha que t1, no será agregado al set
t3.setDate(stringToDate("2016-09-02 04:00:00"));
setTemperaturas.add(t1);
setTemperaturas.add(t2);
setTemperaturas.add(t3);
System.out.println(setTemperaturas);

//método stringToDate
//deberías manejar las excepciones de otra manera
static Date stringToDate(String s) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        return sdf.parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problema al parsear fecha " + s, ex);
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
[ 1-Fri Sep 02 04:00:00 GMT -5 2016, 2-Fri Sep 03 04:00:00 GMT -5 2016 ]
```

Comment: Hola Luiggi Mendoza ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo en tu desarrollo de los métodos equals y hashCode que deben ir en la otra clase?. Estoy intentando implementar en mi código tu explicación para que se pueda ver toda la estrucutura de tu explicación en tu solución, así también otros podrán implementarlo sin hacer de nuevo la pregunta. Muchas gracias

Comment: El ejemplo me parece conciso y extrapolable a otras situaciones (es más, así aprendí yo). ¿Tu duda es sobre una buena implementación para los métodos `equals` y `hashCode`? ¿O qué es lo que ahora buscas?

Comment: Sí, mi duda es como implentarlos los dos métodos en la otra clase- Es conciso y extrapolable, en eso estamos deacuerdo. He buscado toda la información sobre ello, hash, hashcode y equals, He leido sobre cuando usar equals con Strings y el uso de == con primitivos y que hay que definir los criterios de igualdad, Sobre Hashcode, HashMap y HashSet y sus usos en claves, también he estado documentándome, pero sería de gran ayuda entenderlo dentro de tu ejemplo pues no soy programador. Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: ¿En qué clase necesitas implementarlo? Solo define el campo o los campos que necesitas que definan la igualdad (en este caso, el campo elegido fue `insertadoTemp`) e implementa los métodos `equals` y `hashCode` tomando ese campo o campos como base. Si tu duda es cómo generar un `hashCode` a partir de múltiples campos, puedes usar `Objects#hash(campo1, campo2, campo3...)` que ya viene desde Java 7 o [copiar sus fuentes](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Objects.java#Objects.hash%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) en tu proyecto

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias, voy a ver lo que me comentas.